# Is this called a metaphor or how would you describe it?

Tags: grammar, metaphors

I posted a photo of me on social media back when I was living in a different country, doing a different job, living a different kind of life.

So much has changed in my life since then that it ***seems like*** a different lifetime.

I posted the photo with the caption ''Me in my previous life''

Now of course I wasn't implying that it was literally my previous life. I was implying that so much has changed in my life since then that it's ***as if*** it was a different life.

One person commented ''You should say: an earlier part of my life'' and went into a big literal explanation of how my comment implied reincarnation.

I want to know what the grammatical term for what I was using here. Was it a kind of metaphor or something else ?

Comment: I would call that a metaphor, yes. Your caption was fine as posted, that's a common way to express that concept; the commenter was being ridiculously over-literal.

Comment: I'm sure a more precise term will be showing up soon. What you published was a *Description* of a distant part of your life. Since you only said *Seems Like* you were not making any literal claim at all but just describing the great difference in your life from then to now. Your earlier life is actually different than the current one, from childhood to adulthood to old age, they are very different indeed. Your online critic going on about *literal* meanings seems to be trapped in one of those.

Comment: @Elliott - Not that the published caption didn't say "seems like", those words were part of the explanation in the question.

Comment: It's subtly different from a metaphor. A metaphor uses a comparison _with a member of a disjoint set_. For example, _John's a tiger_. It becomes confusing and/or silly to choose another member of a fairly tightly knit set (that lion's a tiger), although no doubt it can work if handled expertly, to be humorous or quirky. // Here, 'me in a previous life' is certainly idiomatic, and stresses the vast change in lifestyle that has occurred. Since literal rebirth hasn't occurred, I'd class this as (well constructed) hyperbole.

Comment: We can say *His life as a pensioner is very different to his life as a working man* without having to suppose that's "metaphoric" usage simply because we know there's no rebirth/reincarnation involved. By the same token I see nothing metaphoric about OP's photo caption. But ***opinions may differ***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, your example of a **different** life is different from the OP's case. One's life as a pensioner may be qualitatively different to one's life as a working man, with both still being parts of what is numerically one and the same life. The OP's wording, on the other hand, was '**previous** life': if that wording were taken literally, it would imply a numerical difference (i.e. that two distinct lives are involved).

Comment: Another life, an earlier life, different times—all informal (and grammatical) expressions in informal English. No implication of reincarnation.

Comment: @jsw29: I wouldn't make too much of that. My example could just as well have been *His [**current**] life as a pensioner is very different to his **previous** life as a working man*. And surely you wouldn't claim that just adding that *particular* adjective switches the utterance from "literal" to "metaphoric" (or indeed, inherently conjures up allusions to reincarnation).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is indeed a simile. Since you made the use of the words, **'it seems'**, your sentence would be considered an example of simile.

Comment: Would you say 'Bill seems like a nice chap' is a simile?

Comment: The OP only used the words "it seems" in his explanation within the question, he didn't use them in the photo caption that somebody objected to.

Answer (score 1):

Simile directly compares two things(unrelated) by the use of like or as. Hyperbole, on the other hand is an exaggeration and is devoid of words like as or like.

Comment: There's no reason why hyperbole can't employ a simile.

Comment: No, "Hyperbole" is a football game played in the US every February!

Answer (score -1):

I would term your example a simple comparison ([Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/comparison)).

It's neither a [metaphor](https://www.lexico.com/definition/metaphor) (a hidden comparison) nor a [simile](https://www.lexico.com/definition/simile) (an unusual comparison) as they're figures of speech.

Comment: Seems *like* a simile to me.